# Change the ADO.NET Entity Data Model default EF version?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, visual-studio-2013

i'm pretty new in EF and I was triying to import a database to my project (MVC4) using ADO.NET Entity Data Model (edmx). In the setup after I selected the server and database it asked me about what EF version i want to use, then i just choose EF 6. When i tried to make a controller with actions for modify, read/write and views template i got a prompt saying MVC scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6. So i went to remake the de edmx but this time there was not a setup screen asking for EF version and now it looks as that is the default EF version.

Is there some way to change the default EF version for edmx setup?

I'm using: 
- VS 2013 
- C# 
- SQL Server 10

I've tried:
- Change the EF version in the packages.config
- Remake the project
- Install EF 5 in the PMC (Nuget)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaffolding using Entity Framework 6 in  MVC 4 is not supported its for Future MVC version.To get previous version of EF try adding reference to project of `System.Data.Entity  v4.0.0.0` in Add Reference>Assemblies>Framework .If not present try installing EF v4.0 from Microsoft Website
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=8363 ,and then add reference

Comment: Thank you very much. I just uninstalled the EF using the PMC and deleted its reference from packages.config. Then I installed it again with the PMC :)